how do I resolve the check and cast error on omnetpp
When I run the leach project I downloaded from github, I get check_and_cast errorenter image description here.Can someone help me see what went wrong，Thank you!
leach.cc
        ICcEnergyStorage *energyStorageModule = check_and_cast<ICcEnergyStorage *>(host->getSubmodule("energyStorage"));
        C residualCapacity = energyStorageModule->getResidualChargeCapacity();

        eventLogEntry nodeEvent;
        nodeEvent.srcNodeName = srcNodeName;
        nodeEvent.destNodeName = destNodeName;
        nodeEvent.time = simTime().dbl()*1000;
        nodeEvent.packet = packet;
        nodeEvent.type = type;
        nodeEvent.residualCapacity = residualCapacity;
        eventLog.push_back(nodeEvent);`
*.ini
*.host*.energyStorage.typename = "SimpleEpEnergyStorage"
*.host[*].energyStorage.initialCapacity = 0.5J      # Sets the initial battery capacity of a node

*.host[*].energyManagement.typename = "SimpleEpEnergyManagement"
*.host[*].energyManagement.nodeShutdownCapacity = 0.1 * energyStorage.nominalCapacity

I've tried a lot of things but I'm still getting the error.
